# What is the best option when using relational database to separate users?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project Dental Clinic using PHP and MySql. I realize that
my logic gets complicated because I separate Patient and User. To make this
clear, let me show you my table:

**patient_table:**

```
id, 
username, 
password, 
birthday, 
age, 
mobile_number, 
full_address, 
gender, 
nickname,
occupation
```

**user_table:**

Here in user_table, you can see user_role column.
The possible values are admin/dentist.

```
id,
full_name,
user_role,
username,
password,
birthday,
age,
mobile_number,
full_address,
created_at
```

---

The question is, should I include patient role in user_table user_role column?
What would be the best way to go about it? Any suggestion?

Comment: Depends on business logic.

Comment: @Akina do you think is it a good idea to make 2 login form for the patient_table and user_table depending on user role admin/dentist? Or include the patient info to user_table and then they can login with the same login form based on user_role?

Assuming that the user_role values are admin/dentist/patient

Ex: SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = $username AND password = $password AND user_role = $userRole

Comment: I think that one form with a field "I am authorized as .." may be enough.. or 3 checkboxes - for each role. Anycase I do not see the reason in 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can create a new table with user roles (id, user_id, role), but you can stay this column in `user_table`.

Comment: Do you think is it a good idea to make 2 login form for the patient_table and user_table depending on user role admin/dentist? Or include the patient info to user_table and then they can login with the same login form based on user_role?

Comment: If they have a same data, you can use only one table `user_table`

Answer (score 0):

The person information should be in 1 table no need to separate to 2 table in small system. As example, every person have username and password for login application.

tbPerson

PersonID,
Username,
Password,
BirthDate,

Age, >> remove this column and calculate from birthdate

MobileNumber,
FullAddress,
Gender,
Nickname,
Occupation,

UserRole, >> admin/patient/dentist or if you want more flexible you should creat user_role_table for all type of role

CreatedAt,

additional column suggestion
IsEnableLogin,
UpdateBy,
UpdateDate,
CreateBy,
CreateDate

Comment: Okay noted, so I should change my logic, include the patient info to user_table since they are related. but is it a good idea to make 2 login form for the patient_table and user_table depending on user role admin/dentist? Or include the patient info to user_table and then they can login with the same login form based on user_role?